# XUBUNTU - multiple display. Move only one at a time

Tags: xubuntu, display, xfce

How can I use different workspaces in a way that my computer's dispay doesn't move when the additional screen moves, (e.g. as in Mac)?
e.g. if you have 2 displays, 1 belonging to your computer and another attached display. When you change the workspace in attached display, then both the display's and your computer's workspace changes. I wan them to change independently of one another.

Comment: I'm not a MAC user, what do you mean by "when the additional screen moves"?

Comment: I've added explanation

Comment: You will need to find a way to run a different instance of xfce on each monitor, I am sure it is possible, but you will probably need to play around with the config files. Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19340/how-can-i-run-a-separate-x-session-on-a-different-physical-display